# Variables in SOAP endpoint

Tags: soap, wsdl, endpoints

I'm writing a proxy for some services that have industry standard wsdls. The project's goal is to have all participants send their requests to the proxy, regardless of format, and we will wrap the messages and send it on to the intended target.

However, figuring out who the intended target is has become a difficult problem. I have considered modifying the WSDL's to include an additional SOAP header, but I want to avoid modifying well known industry wsdls as much as possible.

The other option I have is to use endpoints with some variable in them. `/<network>/<service>/` is the existing endpoint scheme for services. I would like to make this `/<network>/<service>/<target>/`, but only use the `<target>` for logic inside of the actual code. I do not want to set up a separate endpoint for each `<target>` as they are variable, and would be the same service and wsdl no matter what its contents are.

I have not been able to find a way to define SOAP endpoints in a way that `/<network>/<service>/*/` would be valid. Is this possible? If so, what is the best way of doing it?

Answer (score 0):

We use a header section to store routing information and user id, and general metadata.

But if you don't want to do that, maybe [WS-Addressing](http://www.w3.org/Submission/ws-addressing/) is relevant? It is standardized, at least.  I think you still have to have a header though.

"A Web service endpoint is a (referenceable) entity, processor, or resource where Web service messages can be targeted. Endpoint references convey the information needed to identify/reference a Web service endpoint, and may be used in several different ways: endpoint references are suitable for conveying the information needed to access a Web service endpoint, but are also used to provide addresses for individual messages sent to and from Web services. To deal with this last usage case this specification defines a family of message information headers that allows uniform addressing of messages independent of underlying transport. These message information headers convey end-to-end message characteristics including addressing for source and destination endpoints as well as message identity."

Comment: I was under the impression that WS-Addressing was the standard way of storing routing information in SOAP messages. The issue with WS-Addressing is that our partners may not know the exact address where they intend to send to. They may only know the organization's name, and it appears that specifying anything other than a valid URI in the To: field would break the spec.

When you say you put routing information in the SOAP headers, did you design your own way of doing that, or are you using WS-Addressing?

Comment: No, we don't use WS-Addressing - sorry, I was just reading about it and thought maybe it was useful.  So yeah, we just define our own header with an XSD, and have a <destination>X</destination> field in there, which is used to choose the data source from the entity manager.

Comment: What language are you using for the service?  Presumably you can configure multiple endpoints to point to the same service, but you'll probably need to make an endpoint for each target.  I doubt you'll be able to use a wildcard technique.

Comment: It was up in the air, but I've settled on Java over Python for this job. I considered standing up endpoints for each possible combination, but that is too much work, hard to maintain and understand from a code perspective. I settled on not doing dynamic endpoints, and instead just using query params. Though they are typically seen in REST, I can just ask the senders to send the extra information we need for routing as a part of their request url. `http://foo.com/soap/endpoint?target='bar'&&moreData='baz'`. Pulling off query params and parsing them is an easier task.